# python linting and subclass properties

Tags: python, pylint, mypy

I have a superclass that uses some properties from the child class.
but unless I define properties in my superclass ALSO then the linter throws errors.

what's a pythonic way to get around this?

```py
# parent
class DigItem:
    def fetch_bq(self):
        query = f'''select * from {self.table_id}'''

# subclass
class ChatLog(DigItem):

    def __init__(self, set_name):
        super().__init__(set_name)
        self.table_id = biglib.make_table_id('chat_logs')
```

The above code errors with:

`Instance of 'DigItem' has no 'table_id' memberpylint(no-member)`

now, I can add the property to the superclass but that's pretty redundant and also risks overwriting the subclass

```py
class DigItem:
    def __init__(self, set_name):
        self.table_id = None # set by child
```

This is down to the linter not being able to know AOT that this is a 'superclass' so it's fair enough as an error in a standalone instance.

But I'd prefer clean linting, pythonic code and not writing special hacky stuff just to shut up the linter.

Comment: Well, nothing prevents you from instantiating a new `DigItem` and calling `fetch_bq` on it - and the linter sees this. I would definitely push the `table_id` to the super-class. Can you move the `make_table_id` code to the constructor of `DigItem`? Where does `super().__init__(set_name)` go?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `DigItem` has no `__init__` at all (so it will be `object`'s), so passing an argument to `super().__init__()` will fail

```py
>>> class A: pass
...
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     super().__init__("something")
...
>>> B()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Further, you should (must) create the missing property in your parent in order for it to meaningfully make use of it in a method (otherwise different inheriting classes will not be able to make use of the method)

```py
>>> class A:
...   def foo(self):
...     return self.bar
...
>>> class B(A):
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.bar = "baz"
...
>>> class C(A): pass  # NOTE .bar is never defined!
...
>>> C().foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in foo
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

If the base class is not intended to be directly instantiable, consider making it an [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)

Comment: You don't need to define an init-function to instantiate the class - but passing an unexpected argument will of course fail. I think maybe OP simplified the code, and missed the super-call bit, since the above code would never run. Lets wait and see. :)

Comment: yeah that's correct, i was trying to simplify on the fly. maybe I'll look into ABCs then